# Jump to where a key binding is defined?

Tags: key-bindings, help

It is possible to jump to the function that a key binding is mapped to (via `describe-key`).
**Is it possible to jump to where the key binding itself is defined?**

## Example

```
(define-key my-mode-map "a" 'my-func) # line 1000 in a file.el
```

I want an interactive function `jump-to-binding`, which will read a binding ("a") and then open `file.el` and go to line 1000.

Comment: `M-x find-variable RET my-mode-map RET` will get you to where you want to be most of the time, but not always since the bindings may be added with a major-mode hook or wrapped in an `eval-after-load` statement.  Another idea would be to grep for `'my-func` or `'my-func)` [using the appropriate backslashes if a regexp search] which may turn up a lot of hits, but then you can isearch for `define-key` in the grep results.

Comment: Yeah `find-variable` combined with an appropriate grep seems to come pretty close to this.

Comment: Also this approach doesn't handle cases where you are doing dynamic / programmatic defining very well. It's interesting, the keybindings you make, and the builtins are very different in nature. Your keybindings will mostly get bound in one place, but never in the same place as the mode, the mode's keybindings get defined in lots of different places but as a rule away from the mode map.

Answer (score 1):

For a key KEY, the following searchs `(define-key _KEYMAP KEY CMD)`
expression in files where KEYMAP and CMD are defined.

```el
;; -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-
(defun jump-to-binding (key)
  (interactive "kJump to binding of key: ")
  (let* ((cmd (key-binding key))
         (cmd-file (find-library-name (symbol-file cmd)))
         (keymap (help--binding-locus key nil))
         (keymap-file (find-library-name (symbol-file keymap)))
         (search-files (seq-uniq
                        (delq nil
                              (list cmd-file keymap-file)))))
    (require 'el-search-x)
    (el-search-setup-search
     (list '\` (list 'define-key ',_ (list '\, `(keys ,key)) `',cmd))
     (lambda () (stream search-files)))))
```

[el-search](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/el-search.html.) is used for searching, you can get the package from GNU ELPA. The command can
work for some keys such as `C-s` (`isearch-forward`) and `C-l`
(`recenter-top-bottom`).

You can improve the command in many ways, for example,

- Search `bindings.el`, many Emacs key bindings is created there
- Search your init file if you want to
- Support `global-set-key`, `bind-key` etc
- Support prefix keymap, for example, `C-x h` should be able to find
  `(define-key ctl-x-map "h" 'mark-whole-buffer)`